# Change symbol and tittle on pdf popup

Tags: html

[image]

How to change symbol and title on pdf popup. Can anyone help?

```
<div>
   <a href="assets/pdf/anti_bribery_policy.pdf" target="blank">PdfFile</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I got by using the below HTML. It assumes that you have file pdficon.png in same folder as html file.

[image]

```
<html>

<head>
<title>Custom Title </title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="x-icon" href="pdficon.png">
</head>

<body>

<div>
   <a href="assets/pdf/anti_bribery_policy.pdf" target="blank">PdfFile</a>
</div>   

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally you have no control over the client, once you dis position the web source to a client as their local file via another tab. Every user can be using a different HTML Editor (Browser application).

The process is in general, as follows.

- The web page with HTML and JS text is received by the clients HTML document browser. See web page in image.
- The JS (if allowed) or Browser setting, can pre-empt the desired page attachments, so the remote icon is downloaded and attached to the HTML page tab along with the page title. **see middle tab in picture**. It may even start to download the PDF to speed up later display.
  [image]
- When the client click on the link (far left) the browser needs to ask the user what they want. That can be a local upload of the downloaded PDF into a locally controlled tab, or save as the previous/new download or even at their choice a new window or application.
  [image]
  **By default most browser PDF editors will use or not a browser system icon for the file in the sandboxed plug-in editor and optionally use the PDFs meta-data "Title" (if it has one) for the tab name.**
  [image]

The new tab is generally never under web control, unless you have a web based extension they have to use for reading PDF.
[image]
[image]